# vb show another page without open a new form(or window)

Tags: .net, vb.net

While running some programs, They sometimes move to next page when we press some button.

eg) In a installation wizard, when we press "Start download", another page which shows downloading statue will appear.

In this situation, The program will Show us new page without showing a new window(=Form in VB).
But in VB, we can open a new form in other window, not the same window it was.
Is it possible in VB .NET to show a new page in the same window??

Comment: You know how forms contain controls? Well, just show a different set of controls if you want a different "page". You can use multiple `Panel` controls so that only the one in front is visible to the user or you can use user controls and add and remove them as required.

Comment: I searched about panel and I find that I could use it as design form or group componets,  but I couldn't find how panel could be hide or be visible. is there a good site that let me know well about panel?? There are few korean sites even tell me what is panel and translated microsoft developer netwrk is almost not understandable, I wish somebody is kind enough to  give me some help...

Comment: [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?863663-Creating-a-Wizard-Form-with-Multiple-Panels) is one I prepared earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple task. A very simple example:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Myform As New Form
    Myform.TopLevel = False
    Myform.BackColor = Color.Azure
    Myform.ControlBox = False
    Myform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Controls.Add(Myform)
    Myform.Visible = True
End Sub
```